# QCA lib building via cmake

Tags: qt, cmake

I got the following error code after i built the QCA lib to a seperat directory as the CMakeLists.txt exists.

I got Qt 6.

```
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:47 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" (requested
  version 5.9) with any of the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/SDK/qca-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: As you can see the QCA version you're trying to build needs Qt5. So Qt6 is no option for this version.

Comment: Sry, my bad, Thanks!